# Can Intransitive verbs such as "arrive" take objects?

Tags: locative, transitivity

I am learning English grammar. I am not a beginner and I am following an English grammar book to improve my grammar.
The book gives some examples of *intransitive verbs* (verbs that don't take any objects) like **come, go, arrive**.
An example is given below from the book

> We arrived at 11.

Now my question is: Isn't it confusing? I can say *We arrived at the airport.* or *I came to school.*

How can there be intransitive verbs or verbs that don't take objects?

Answer (score 4):

Ok I think I got it now. Basically when we say

> We arrived at the airport.

the airport is not an object for verb arrive. So we can't say `We arrived the airport` or something like that

Comment: Congratulations! You got it exactly right!

Comment: "at the airport" is a where-indication, and not a direct object. As a sentence part it is called adverbial (sentence part). Verbs of movement don't have  direct objects.

Comment: Nor do verbs of being.  Like "be". Examples:  I am cold. (cold = predicate adjective)  I am my father's son. (son = predicate nominative)

Comment: I think another way to see it is that "at the airport" is a prepositional phrase attached to the sentence "We arrived".